# How to bind function to object property?

Tags: angular, angular7

There is a class with methods:

```
public add() {}
public delete(item: Ivoice) {}
```

And method for mapping these methods inside object:

```
    this.invoices = data.map(item => {
            item.add = this.add;
            item.edit = this.delete;
            return item;
   });
```

Then in template I tried to call method as:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <span (click)="item.add(item)">
</div>
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, The Simplest Way would be:
Have a Method:

```
public void executeClickOrSomething(YourType type){
    type.add(type)
}
```

And Then you can do this in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of invoices; let i = index">
  <span (click)="executeClickOrSomething(item)">
</div>
```

**An Advice:**
Always have separate methods for Complex scenarios. Although This doesn't Sound that complex but still, Angular is still under development so maybe they'll fix it in the Future...

**NOTE:**
If You are thinking of changing the Original DataSource/Array(In this case), then you should overwrite that element in that DataSource/Array as Well..

Answer (score 0):

Although, it is not clear, what you are really trying to achieve, but technically the problem lies here:

```js
item.add = this.add;
item.edit = this.delete;
```

You are basically assigning the function/method references to the `item` object. Next time you call the method over `item`, a la item.add(item) within your template, then the method/function will invoked at `item`'s scope, and not your class", i.e. ItemComponent, scope, which apparently the desired behaviour.

You can use the [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to avoid this problem:

```js
item.add = this.add.bind(this);
item.edit = this.delete.bind(this);
```